# What is a Pacific Rim recipe?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it the recipe of a dish?

> Here’s a Pacific Rim recipe for success. Start with a newly arrived immigrant to the U.S. from Beijing—whose visa was rejected the first eight times he applied. Have the young man take a job at a California startup with fewer than 50 employees, whose two founders were from Beijing and Mumbai. Next step: get Silicon Valley giant Cisco to buy the young company, WebEx, whose service is videoconferencing.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/richkarlgaard/2020/09/16/why-zoom-is-booming/#dd763d3d33b3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A “recipe for success” is an idiom that implies that if you follow the same pattern (behavior) with the same ingredients (people), then you will get the same result (success), just like a recipe for cooking. But it  is almost always hyperbole; there are no such guarantees in life.

The “Pacific Rim” refers to cities on the Pacific Ocean, or in this case, the people who live in those cities.